# High performance server side rendering with Node.js in Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, next.js

We're currently in an evaluation phase for **S**erver **S**ide **R**endering with [React](https://reactjs.org/).

Our current rendering stack is based on the JVM and provides us a performance of **~2k req/sec** with a mean **~150-200 ms/req**. This is the performance we want to achieve at least with the new stack.

We deployed prototypes (React + express.js & and with next.js) with a reasonable amount of components (10k elements in DOM) in our Kubernetes cluster and measured their performance with [autocannon](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon).

For simplicity, focus on the next.js prototype.

While our first tests with one concurrent user were quite good, we saw dramatically drops in response times when increasing the concurrency level. With our knowledge on how Node.js works (single-threaded event-loop) we assume this is because of a lagging event loop.

While thinking about to protect the event loop of the service with libraries such [overload-protection](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/overload-protection) we asks ourselfs if this is really the way to go?

For example, the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/build-target) of next.js says that 'serverless' is the recommended build target.

What is your experience in rendering React components a high-performance way on the server side? Any advice on using the `serverless` build target? Or should we stick on next.js's default build target `server`? If so, what is a good strategy to handle a overloading event loop in the cluster? How to load balance that?

We really appreciate if you can share your knowledge! Really! :)

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: You can trivially run the same server app in multiple processes (thus multiple event loops and actual concurrency) with e.g. https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: Thanks @AKX for your comment. Like descried [here](https://youtu.be/Zgx0o8QjJk4?t=972) we do not need a process manager within our containers. We can create multiple processes/pods with kubernetes.

Comment: You don't _need_ one, but you definitely can run one, and I think it might solve your problem with the least effort. Why not give it a shot?

Comment: @AKK Kubernetes provides that facility by launching multiple pods (processes) for an application and sharing traffic between them

Comment: @chrgue what did profiling of the node process say was busy?

Comment: @Matt I am perfectly aware Kubernetes can do that, but it also requires load-balancing between pods, while in this case I believe that's unnecessary.

Comment: I'm just trying to say the pm2 approach ends up pretty similar in concept to what a k8s deployment with replicas already has. Cluster/pm2 round robins connections to local node processes. k8s services round robin connections to cluster processes.

Comment: I agree with @Matt here.

Comment: @Matt The process is busy for rendering (renderToString). As I tried to explain in my question, the bad response times happen in the case of concurrent requests. With only one request after another we have good results (60ms/request).

Comment: @chrgue I wouldn't worry about the event loop, apart from running a node.js process per core you want to utilise (similar to the number of java threads previously). At 60ms you get ~16 serial requests a second. That's 125 node pods/processes to hit 2k/s. Pre render as much as possible, use stateless components, limit the dom tree and dive into what in react is taking the time. The other thing to keep in mind is ss react is just heavier weight than simple templating.

Comment: I still think simply running multiple processes might be the easiest way to get more throughput here. See also https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay#the-docker-way